# Freezable DataContext

Tags: wpf

I have a `customControl` like `ListView` and I need to bind the sub property of my Custom Control to the visual tree element like below,

```
<StackPanel>    
    <TextBlock  Text="Test" x:Name="txtBlock" />
    <local:MyControl>
          <local:MyControl.Items>
                <local:MyControlItem Value ="{Binding ElementName=txtBlock, Path=Text}" />    
          </local:MyControl.Items>
    </local:MyControl>    
</StackPanel>
```

I can access the object using `Freezable` object as the resource, but i want to inherit `Freezable` in my `MyControlItem` and access the Visual Tree.

I want to bind Value property in `MyControlItem` with the `textBlock`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the following link,

http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/05/22/leveraging-freezables-to-provide-an-inheritance-context-for-bindings/