# Binding doesn't work on DependencyObject created in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I'm trying to pass multiple CommandParameters in XAML with the use of a custom class.

I have created a class called *ValueCommandArgs* that inherits from **DependencyObject** and has two DepencyProperties (lets call them *Value1* and *Value2* for this example).

The button which is supposed to call a command and pass this object looks like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChangeValueCommand}" Content="Execute Command">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <args:ValueCommandArgs Value1="{Binding TestValue1}" Value2="{Binding TestValue2}" />
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

I do get an ValueCommandArgs-Object in my command as paramter, however the properties *Value1* and *Value2* **are always null/empty**.

I know this can be solved with a MultiBinding and Converter, but I think the way I'm trying it would be a cleaner approach.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Are you getting binding errors in your output window?

Comment: I think the Binding is failed. You expected that the `DataContext` was passed down to the `ValueCommandArgs` but I think it could not be. I also don't know how to implement some type which can receive the DataContext passed down to it. In this case you should explicitly set the `Source` for your Binding. (note that `ElementName` and `RelativeSource` are usable only if your `ValueCommandArgs` inherits from FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement).

Comment: You will need a binding proxy check this out - http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/

Comment: @NovitchiS That solves the problem; perhaps consider writing it up as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I will write an answer with why the binding does not work and how the proxy solves the issue as soon as i got a few minutes.

Comment: @NovitchiS Ok, 2y later, still doesnt got few minutes? :) (Thanks for the link anyway, it solve my problem... But i was praying to all gods that the link is not dead...)

Answer (score 2):

A `Binding` needs a source object to be able to provide a value. When the Binding source is not specified (with `Source` or `ElementName` etc.) eg: `Value1="{Binding TestValue1}"` the `DataContext` of the element is used.

The `args:ValueCommandArgs` object does not inherit the `DataContext` from the `Button` element because property value inheritance is particularly about how property values can inherit from one element to another on the basis of the parent-child relationships **within a tree of elements**.

The button object does not include the value of the `CommandParameter` property in its logical nor the visual tree.

In many cases the need for such a `CommandParameter` with multiple bound values can be avoided by binding the values directly to the ViewModel.

When it can't be avoided you can use a different type of binding markup extension like: https://github.com/JohanLarsson/Gu.Reactive#ninjabinding that will use the root `FrameworkElement` as the source of the binding.

Another approach would be a binding proxy technique shown in this blog post: [How to bind to data when the DataContext is not inherited](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)